# Python: How Can I Get This to Understand the Input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a Spanish trivia game, but I'm having a difficult time getting the random questions to accept the answers as the answers to that question. As it is right now, the code ends up simply recycling back to the question until all three guesses have been made. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

```
from random import randint

starting_line = 0
Comp_startingline = 0
finish_line = 100

guess_count = 0
limit_of_guesses = 3

player_1 = 0

player1 = randint(1,10)
computer = randint(1,10)
questions = randint(1,10)


# The questions that will come up in racing
if questions == 1:
    questions = ("Hola, como estas, Carlos?")
    answer = "Hello, how are you, Carlos?"
    if questions == answer:
        print ("You are correct!")

elif questions == 2:
    questions = ("Me llamo, Mateo!")
    answer1 = "My name is Matthew!"
    if questions == answer1:
        print ("You are correct!")

elif questions == 3:
    questions = ("Que rabia!")
    answer2 = "What rage!"
    if questions == answer2:
        print ("You are correct!")

elif questions == 4:
    questions = ("Amigo!")
    answer3 = "Friend!"
    if questions == answer3:
        print ("You are correct!")

elif questions == 5:
    questions = ("Me nombre es.")
    answer4 = "My name is."
    if questions == answer4:
        print ("You are correct!")

elif questions == 6:
    questions = ("Le gusta?")
    answer5 = "Do you like him?"
    if questions == answer5:
        print ("You are correct!")

elif questions == 7:
    questions = ("Soy escritor")
    answer6 = "I am a writer."
    if questions == answer6:
        print ("You are correct!")

elif questions == 8:
    questions = ("Me gusta musica!")
    answer7 = "I like music!"
    if questions == answer7:
        print ("You are correct!")

elif questions == 9:
    questions = ("Que estado?")
    answer8 = "What state?"
    if questions == answer8:
        print ("You are correct!")

else:
    questions = ("De donde eres?")
    answer9 = "Where are you from?"
    if questions == answer9:
        print ("You are correct!")



while starting_line != finish_line:
    player_1_progress = starting_line + player1
    Computer_progress = computer + Comp_startingline
    print(questions)
    if guess_count < limit_of_guesses:
        answer = input("What did the phrase say? ")
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        print("Wah, wah, wahhh! Better luck next time!")
        break
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is fundamentally wrong, you should try something like this:

```
# The questions that will come up in racing
phrases = {
    "Hola, como estas, Carlos?": "Hello, how are you, Carlos?",
    "Me llamo, Mateo!": "My name is Matthew!",
    "Que rabia!": "What rage!",
    "Amigo!": "Friend!",
    "Me nombre es.": "My name is.",
    "Le gusta?": "Do you like him?",
    "Soy escritor": "I am a writer.",
    "Me gusta musica!": "I like music!",
    "Que estado?": "What state?",
    "De donde eres?": "Where are you from?"
}

for phrase, answer in phrases.items():
    while not input(f"What does that mean:\n{phrase}\n> ") == answer:
        print("Wrong answer try again ! :o(")
```

I am not saying this code does everything you want it to, but it will help you to implement the rest of your functionnalities.

Answer (score 0):

You're using python in it's unintended fashion. You're writing a procedural program in an Object oriented programming language.

**My suggestion:**

Create a `dict` of all the questions and answers, use a loop to keep asking questions either a while loop and stop when all questions are exhausted or for loop and randomize all the questions. This way you will only need one condition block (to check if they were right).

For the computer just make a random number from 0 to the number of questions the computer doesn't need to answer every question it just needs to be randomly right or wrong.

Comment: Thank you so much, Jaba. I'm very new to Python.

Comment: I implemented this in my answer, it should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can consolidate the if condition in the while loop as below:

```
from random import randint

starting_line = 0
Comp_startingline = 0
finish_line = 100

guess_count = 0
limit_of_guesses = 3

player_1 = 0

player1 = randint(1,10)
computer = randint(1,10)
questions = randint(1,10)


# The questions that will come up in racing
if questions == 1:
    questions = ("Hola, como estas, Carlos?")
    answer_default = "Hello, how are you, Carlos?"


elif questions == 2:
    questions = ("Me llamo, Mateo!")
    answer_default = "My name is Matthew!"

elif questions == 3:
    questions = ("Que rabia!")
    answer_default = "What rage!"

elif questions == 4:
    questions = ("Amigo!")
    answer_default = "Friend!"

elif questions == 5:
    questions = ("Me nombre es.")
    answer_default = "My name is."

elif questions == 6:
    questions = ("Le gusta?")
    answer_default = "Do you like him?"

elif questions == 7:
    questions = ("Soy escritor")
    answer_default = "I am a writer."

elif questions == 8:
    questions = ("Me gusta musica!")
    answer_default = "I like music!"

elif questions == 9:
    questions = ("Que estado?")
    answer_default = "What state?"

else:
    questions = ("De donde eres?")
    answer_default = "Where are you from?"



while starting_line != finish_line:
    player_1_progress = starting_line + player1
    Computer_progress = computer + Comp_startingline
    print(questions)
    if guess_count < limit_of_guesses:
        answer = input("What did the phrase say? ")
        guess_count += 1
        if answer == answer_default:
            print ("You are correct!")
            break
    else:
        print("Wah, wah, wahhh! Better luck next time!")
        break
```

However, I encourage you to slowly approach a optimized coding in python once you are done with it.

Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0):

There are some critical errors in your program's logic. Since the code executes from top to bottom, the `questions` variable will only be generated once, therefore it will keep asking the same question. Also the answer is never properly checked. You use `if questions == answer` which will never be true since the question is not the same as the answer. Furthermore this line will be executed before the user is able to input their own answer.

Here is is a sample to get you on the right track. I'll let you figure out how to prevent duplicate questions and whatever other features you intended.

```
from random import randint

def generate_question():
    question_num = randint(1, 2)

    if question_num == 1:
        question = "Hola, como estas, Carlos?"
        answer = "Hello, how are you, Carlos?"
    else:
        question = "Me llamo, Mateo!"
        answer = "My name is Matthew!"

    return question, answer

def main():
    guess_count = 0
    limit_of_guesses = 3

    while guess_count < limit_of_guesses:
        # Generate a new question
        question, answer = generate_question()

        # Ask question and get user's answer
        print(question)
        users_answer = input("What did the phrase say?")
        # Check the answer
        if answer == users_answer:
            print("You are correct!\n")
        else:
            print("Wah, wah, wahhh! Better luck next time!\n")

        guess_count += 1

    print("Gameover!")

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code never checks the answer, so it does not determine correctness.

When you have a big list of data like this, it's usually a good idea to consider putting it into a list (or loading it from a file).

Below I made the questions a list of Q & A pairs.  This can be referenced like:

```
question, answer = question_text[question_number]
```

Or separately like:

```
question = question_text[question_number][0]
answer   = question_text[question_number][1]
```

This gives simpler code.  When checking the answer, it's always easier for the user if the computer takes care to not check excess spaces, or word captialisation.  This can be handled with python string `strip()` and `lower()` in the comparison.

```
from random import randint

starting_line = 0
Comp_startingline = 0
finish_line = 100

guess_count = 0
limit_of_guesses = 3

player_1 = 0

player1 = randint(1,10)
computer = randint(1,10)
question_number = randint(1,10)

question_text = [
              [ "Hola, como estas, Carlos?", "Hello, how are you, Carlos?" ],
              [ "Me llamo, Mateo!", "My name is Matthew!" ],
              [ "Que rabia!", "What rage!" ],
              [ "Amigo!", "Friend!" ],
              [ "Me nombre es.", "You are correct!" ],
              [ "Le gusta?", "Do you like him?" ],
              [ "Soy escritor", "I am a writer." ],
              [ "Me gusta musica!", "I like music!" ],
              [ "Que estado?", "What state?" ],
              [ "De donde eres?", "Where are you from?" ]
            ]

while starting_line != finish_line:
    player_1_progress = starting_line + player1
    Computer_progress = computer + Comp_startingline
    print(question_text[question_number][0])
    if guess_count < limit_of_guesses:
        answer = input("What did the phrase say? ")
        if (answer.strip().lower() == question_text[question_number][1].strip().lower()):
            print("Correct")
            question_number = randint(1,10)
        else:
            guess_count += 1
    else:
        print("Wah, wah, wahhh! Better luck next time!")
        break
```